# How much time do I have to do the “accommodation registration at local police station” after changing location in China?

Tags: paperwork, china, accommodation, regulations

How much time do I have to do the “accommodation registration at local police station” after changing location in China?

---

From the back of the departure card given by the Chinese immigration while entering China:

[image]

but it doesn't state the allowed amount of time to declare a change of accommodation.

Comment: Are you staying in a hotel or in private accommodation?

Comment: @Doc  private accommodation

Answer (score 1):

A comment on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CWbvmmRQeY&t= from  [JP World Expat](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAEp_XD_vYSskFOrGaZ3APQ) seems to indicate that it's safer to register with the local police station within 24 hours after signing the housing contract:

> They fined me a few RMB recently because I just moved to Hangzhou. I was staying in a hotel while looking for an apartment. I found an apartment, signed the contract and paid 3 months rent upfront but I still remained in the hotel 2 more days then checked out and fully moved in the apartment. The police said I had 24 hours to report this new housing contract as soon as I signed it regardless of not yet checking out of the hotel.